# Nativescript Angular async pipe in listview not showing elements

Tags: angular, rxjs, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to get a basic `ListView` to be populated by a `BehaviourSubject` using the `async` pipe.

The markup code is very simple :

> component.html

```
<ListView [items]="$photos | async" separatorColor="transparent">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
        <Label>{{ item.upid }}</Label>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

Next in the component I use the `push` `ChangeDetectionStrategy`,subscribe to the service responsible to data retrieval and populate the `BehaviourSubject`.
Here is the relevant code :

> component.ts

```
user: ComunicationModels.UserDto = {};
  photos: Array<ComunicationModels.PhotoDto> = [];
  $photos: BehaviorSubject<Array<ComunicationModels.PhotoDto>>;

  constructor(...) {
      this.$photos = new BehaviorSubject([]);
      this.user.photos.forEach(
        (idPhoto) => {
          this.postService.getPhoto(idPhoto)
            .subscribe((p) => {
              this.photos.push(p);
              this.$photos.next([...this.photos]);
              // console.dir(this.$photos.value); -> This shows correct information
            });
        });
  }
```

I don't get errors, but my listview is completely empty not showing up any items... what am I missing?

Comment: Could you share the code for ListView as well? I created a little example, everything seems to be working, have a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ikswrj